# rails partial does not generate events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, partial

I have a form that is rendered via a partial. When the available fields for selection in the form change either by a submit event in this form or a delete event in another form this form needs to be redrawn.  No matter the cause when the form is redrawn no events are detected, prior to getting the form redrawn/rendered I can have the submit buttons register in the console output.

The code that produces a log message to the console - works until the form is rendered dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("On Ready")
  $(document).on('submit', '.ioConnect', function(event){
    console.log("Button Clicked");
    event.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

This is the form that is being rendered in the partial _links.html.erb

```
<table style="border: 1px solid;">    
    <tr>    
      <th>Create New Link</th>    
    </tr>

    <% @vehicle_configuration.recursive_outputs_array.each do |output| %>    
      <tr>    
        <%= form_for InputToOutputLink.new, :html => { class: 'ioConnect'} do |f| %>
          <td>Link </td>
          <td><%= output.friendly_name %><%= f.hidden_field :output_id, {:value => output.id} %></td>
          <td> to </td>
          <td><%= f.collection_select :input_id, @vehicle_configuration.unused_inputs_hash_for_output_type(output), :first, :last , { class: 'outputConnectionSelection' } %></td>
          <td>
            <%= f.hidden_field :vehicle_configuration_id, {:value => @vehicle_configuration.id} %>
            <%= f.submit "Connect", :html => { class: 'ioConnectSubmit'} %>
          </td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

This is the line that causes the form to be redrawn either on a creation or deletion of a link

```
$("#create-links-container").html("<%= j( render('/vehicle_designer/links')).html_safe %>");
```

I am sure it is related to the form being redrawn and the need to reconnect the events but I am not sure how to do that.  I thought by listening to the submit on a parent element that was not being redrawn would have worked which is what I think I am doing in the first code snippet shown above.

What am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

try events such as "ajax:before", "ajax:success",... because the form is submitted by jquery-ujs
https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts but I cannot see how this is going to help because the jquery-ujs does not seem to be firing again after the redraw of the partial.  The only reason I have tried to capture the button click in the console is to prove whether or not it was working.  Looking at the logs there is nothing being submitted to the server when I allow the remote: true option in the form_for